# Is it possible to subclass NSSavePanel?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, subclass, nssavepanel

I am wondering if there is a way to subclass NSSavePanel. Or if you were to create a dummy object, how would you mimic the beginSheetModalForWindow:CompletionHandler function of NSSavePanel?

```
-(void)beginSheetModalForWindow:(NSWindow *)window completionHandler:(void (^)(NSInteger *))handler{
```

I am blanking out on how to implement the block handler when implementing the function in the .m class file.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Why do you want to subclass NSSavePanel?

Comment: Just working with a plugin that requires one to be returned. I mainly just want to recreate the beginsheetmodalforwindow from NSSavePanel.

Comment: @Dan68am - What do you mean "how to implement the block handler"? If you write a method that takes a block then in the method you just call the block using standard function call syntax, you don't "implement" the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: No

Longer Answer: Here Be Dragons

It is possible but stuff will probably break. You can also add methods using a category and they might work, or they might not. The problems arise due to the way NSOpenPanel is implemented to support the App Sandbox - various chicanery is going on behind the scenes and even convenience category methods which just call existing methods on the class can result in errors being reported by OS X and dialogs not to appear. NSOpenPanel is a delicate creature that should be touched as little as possible and only ever with great care.

Wrapping an NSOpenPanel instance in another class is a different story and should not upset it at all. Go that route.

**Addendum re: Comment**

The declaration of `beginSheetModalForWindow` is:

```
- (void)beginSheetModalForWindow:(NSWindow *)window completionHandler:(void (^)(NSInteger result))handler
```

The completion handler gets passed a value indicating which button was pressed. To take action dependant on that you can use a standard `if`:

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel;
NSWindow *hostWindow;
...
[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:hostWindow
                  completionHandler:^(NSInteger returnCode)
                                    {
                                       if (returnCode == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
                                       {
                                          // OK pressed
                                          ...
                                       }
                                       else
                                       {
                                          // Cancel pressed
                                          ...
                                       }

                                    }
];
```

Comment: I will check this as the answer because you have answered the general question. I think I do not have a good understanding of block methods as arguments which is my problem. I want the completion handler to do something when a Cancel button is pressed, or NSOKButton. So `if(handler == NSOKButton){` do something.

Comment: @Dan68am - Added an addendum, HTH.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth answer. Helps me understand this much better

Comment: it is really sad that we cannot customize NSSavePanel

Comment: @iOSCalendarpatchthecode.com – you can *customize* the standard open/save dialogs by adding a [custom view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssavepanel/1525544-accessoryview?language=objc). What you can't easily do is *subclass* them and change the behavior - this disallowed to protect the sandbox restrictions.

Comment: ok. I was a bit vague, I meant customize it to do something as simple as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58550993/nssavepannel-how-to-restrict-user-to-only-save-one-one-set-directory